# Display array in vueJS from JSON file NodeJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js

So I have this JSON file with this data in it:

```
{
    "manufacturers": ["Sony", "Microsoft", "Nintendo", "Kita"]
}
```

This is how I get it in my NodeJS app:

```
let uploadrawdata = fs.readFileSync('./config/upload.json');
let uploaddata = JSON.parse(uploadrawdata);
```

Then I render the view:

```
res.render('users/upload', {uploaddata});
```

After that in my VueJS script I add it like this:

```
manufacturers: [{{uploaddata.manufacturers}}],
```

And in console in displays like this: 
`manufacturers: [Sony,Microsoft,Nintendo,Kita]`

I need it to display like this: `manufacturers: ['Sony', 'Microsoft', 'Nintendo' ,'Kita']`

Could someone help to solve this ?

Comment: Chrome normally displays string arrays with the elements quoted. How are you logging the array without quotes? What browser? What do you see when you run `console.log(typeof uploaddata.manufacturers)`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `mustache` as template engine.

When rendering an array that way `mustache` will iterate it and concatenate the values of the array with the current output. That's why your quotes are missing. It like doing this:

```
var output = 'Sony' + 'Microsoft'
```

In plain JS. The quotes are missing in the final string.

If you want to send the data as a JS object you can do something like this

```
res.render('users/upload', {uploaddata: JSON.stringify(uploaddata)});
```

and parse it on the Vue side

```
manufacturers: JSON.parse('{{uploaddata}}').manufacturers,
```

Notice the apostrophes around `{{uploaddata}}`. Again, mustache will print the string as is, without embedding it in quotes/apostrophes.